Unable to logon to Azure Virtual Desktop with user who has global administrator role
We are implementing AVD and our AVD host is joined to our Entra.
When I try to logon as a user in the Entra that has the global admin role, I am unable to do so.  When I remove the role I am able to logon as the user.
We don't have the ability at the moment to create Conditional Access rules.  Is it possible to do this or do we need to have CDA's or more probably not use the global admin role on the accounts we used to log into RDP.
Thanks
Ben
